# Python - Numerical issues for solving systems of linear equations with LU decomposition

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numerical-methods

### Info

OS: Manjaro Linux

Development Environment: Spyder4 (Python 3.7)

Libs: Numpy

### Issue

Hi,

I wrote a few functions that solve systems of linear equations following these three methods:

1. LU decomposition
2. Jacobi method
3. Gauss-Seidel method

The program runs perfectly. However, the results of the LU decomposition bothers me.
For example, if my matrix A and vector b are

```
A = np.array([[10., -1., 2., 0.],
          [-1., 11., -1., 3.],
          [2., -1., 10., -1.],
          [0., 3., -1., 8.]])
b = np.array([6., 25., -11., 15.])
```

Then my results are

1. LU:[ 0.95034091  1.67840909 -0.9125      1.875     ]
2. Jacobi:[ 1.  2. -1.  1.]
3. Gauss-Seidel:[ 1.  2. -1.  1.]

As you can see the LU gives me a slightly different result. Is it an issue with a round-off or truncation error? Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

---

### Edit1:

I fixed the issue it was simply a bug in the code during LU decomposition. Appreciate everyone's feedback.

### Shared Code Below:

```
def lu_decomposition(matrix_in, b_in, n):

lower = [[0 for x in range(n)]
            for y in range(n)];
upper = [[0 for x in range(n)]
            for y in range(n)];

# Doolittle's Method
# Decomposing matrix into upper and lower matrices
for i in range(n):
    # Upper triangle
    for k in range(i, n):
        # Sigma from j to i for each row k of U
        sum = 0
        for j in range(i):
            sum += lower[i][j] * upper[j][k]
        # Evaluate U for row k
        upper[i][k] = matrix_in[i][k] - sum
        
    # Lower Triangle
    for k in range(i,n):
        if(i == k): # Entry of a diagonal element
            lower[i][i] = 1 
        else:
            # Sigma from j to i for each column k of L
            sum = 0
            for j in range(i):
                sum += (lower[k][j] * upper[j][i])
            # Evaluate L for column k
            lower[k][i] = int( (matrix_in[k][i] - sum)/ upper[i][i])
            
# Perform forward substitution Ly=b
y = [0 for x in range(n)]
lower_inv = np.linalg.inv(lower)
y = np.dot(lower_inv, b_in)

# Perform back substitution Ux=y
x_sol = [0 for x in range(n)]
upper_inv = np.linalg.inv(upper)
x_sol = np.dot(upper_inv, y)

# printing results
# setw is for displaying nicely 
print("Lower Triangular\t\tUpper Triangular"); 

# Displaying the result : 
for i in range(n): 
      
    # Lower 
    for j in range(n): 
        print(lower[i][j], end = "\t");  
    print("", end = "\t"); 

    # Upper 
    for j in range(n): 
        print(upper[i][j], end = "\t"); 
    print(""); 
            
print("Here's the solution for your matrix: ")
print(x_sol)
```

Comment: I think that's much too large to be rounding error for this size problem.

Comment: That is definitely not due to rounding errors, but I could not find anything obvious in the code. Try debugging and checking the value of the variables as you go step by step.

Comment: I thought so. I did try to cast each operation to a float but that didn't really solve it either. I'm sure the issue lies in my limited experience with python and its libraries. Thanks @bnaecker!

Comment: Good ol' step by step debugging. I guess I'll have to grind this one out. Thanks @darcamo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things to address in your code:

- Python doesn't need ; to end a line, python knows when lines end. Python only uses ; to place two lines of code on the same physical line. Like "x=7;print(x)".
- If you don't use a variable in a list comprehension, then it is customary to use an _. For example, [0 for _ in range(10)]. Of course, python has better ways "[0]*10".
- I notice that you import numpy, but you don't use the operations for numpy arrays. This would greatly improve your code (and make it way faster) and make it way easier to read. For example, you can write to and read from an entire row or column all at once. "matrix[0,:]" (1st row), "matrix[:,0]" (1st col).
- There is no need to include the length of your objects in python, since python automatically stores the length of it's objects, which can always be retrieved with the len() builtin.
- Not really important to your code (as you may be doing this for practice), but as you may already know, lu decomposition, already exists, for example scipy.linalg.lu(). In fact, a quick check of linalg.lu(A,True) reveals that you have bugs both in your L and your U.
- It is really weird to see you manually generate the L and U matricies and then proceed to use np.linalg.inv() on the L and U. If you were willing to use the np.linalg.inv() function, then your answer is one line, "np.linalg.inv(A) @ b". Normally, people find L and U to manually solve for X more easily. To find L and U and then use numpy's inverse function, kindof defeats the purpose.
- Although it can be helpful at times, python does not require you to carve out your space in memory before creating objects. Python automatically manages your memory creation and removal (no need to create empty lists of zeros).
- np.dot() is simply the manual way of accessing the "@" operator in python.

Some examples:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg

def lu_dec_solver_v1(A,b):
    return np.linalg.inv(A) @ b

def lu_dec_solver_v2(A,b):
    L, U  = linalg.lu(A,True)
    L_inv = np.linalg.inv(L)
    U_inv = np.linalg.inv(U)
    return U_inv @ (L_inv @ b)

def lu_dec_solver_v3(A,b):
    U = A.copy()
    L = np.identity(len(A))
    for n in range(0,len(A)-1):
        for m in range(n+1,len(A)):
            L[m,n]  = U[m,n]/U[n,n]
            U[m,:] += -L[m,n]*U[n,:]
    L_inv = np.linalg.inv(L)
    U_inv = np.linalg.inv(U)
    return U_inv @ (L_inv @ b)
```

Comment: Initially, I was trying to play around and implement Doolittle's algorithm.  Afterward, use L & U to get the solution. However, I keep getting weird answers and went for half-committed attempts to use NumPy. I'll take your advice to avoid busting my head and fully use the NumPy library. P.S: the ";" are just C/C++ habits.Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: No problem. :-) Yes, ";" is from C, where do you think python got the idea? Remember python is C's child.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want implement the LU decomposition by yourself, [this](https://github.com/dkaramit/ASAP/blob/master/Differential_Equations/python/Rosenbrock/jupyter/LU_decomposition.ipynb) is a code that does not need any external libraries. I append it here, in case you just  want to copy it

```
def Abs(x):
    '''
    Input x  and you'll get the abs.
    '''
    #Not the best way, but it is an easy way to not use numpy
    return (x**2)**0.5


def ind_max(row,N):
    '''
    Find the index of the maximum of a list (row) of lentgth N.
    '''
    _in=0
    _max=row[0]
    i=0
    while i<N:#the end of the row should be included (convension in how I use LUP..)
        if row[i]>_max:
            _max=row[i]
            _in=i
        i+=1
            
    return _in


def Sum(List,N):
    '''
    Calculates the sum of a List of size N
    '''
    s=0
    for i in range(N):
        s+=List[i]
    return s


def index_swap(A,index_1,index_2):
    '''
        index_swap takes an array and interchanges 
         A[index_1] with A[index_2].
         
         Example:
             A=[0,1,2,3]
             index_swap(A,0,2)
             A
             >>[2, 1, 0, 3]
    '''
    
    tmp=A[index_1]
    A[index_1]=A[index_2]
    A[index_2]=tmp
    
    
def apply_permutations_vector(A,P,N):
    '''
    Applies the permutations given by P from LUP
    to a list A of length N, and returns the result.
    Example:
    A=[1,2,5,8,3]
    P=[2,4,0,3,1]

    apply_permutations_vector(A,P,5)
    >>[5, 3, 1, 8, 2]
    '''
    #that is, you make a list like this (P basically gives you the indices of A):)
    
    Ap=[A[ P[i] ] for i in range(N)]

    return Ap
    
def apply_permutations_matrix(M,P,N):
    '''
    Applies the permutations given by P from LUP
    to a N*N array M of length N, and returns the result.
    
    M=[
    [ 0,  2,  2 , 3 , 5],
    [-3, -1,  1 , 5 , 9],
    [ 1, -1,  1 , 4 , 7],
    [ 1, -1,  1 , 0 , 2],
    [ 1, -1,  1 , 0 , 3]
    ]

    P=[2,0,1,4,3]

    apply_permutations_matrix(M,P,5)
    >>[
      [ 1, -1, 1, 4, 7],
      [ 0,  2, 2, 3, 5],
      [-3, -1, 1, 5, 9],
      [ 1, -1, 1, 0, 3],
      [ 1, -1, 1, 0, 2]
      ]
    '''
    Mp=[ [M[ P[i] ][j]for j in range(N)] for i in range(N) ]
    

    return Mp




def LUP(M,N,_tiny=1e-20):
    U=[  [ M[i][j] for j in range(N)] for i in range(N) ]
    L=[  [ 0 if i!=j else 1 for j in range(N)] for i in range(N) ]
    #this is the "permutation vector". if it is e.g. [2 1 0 3] it means you make 0<->2
    P=[  i for i in range(N) ]
    
    for k in range(1,N):
        for i in range(k,N):
            #find the index of the maximum in column
            _col=[Abs(U[_r][k-1]) for _r in range(k-1,N)]
            
            #find the index of the maximum of _col
            # notice that the length of _col is N-(k-1)
            len_col=N-(k-1)
            pivot=ind_max( _col ,len_col) + k - 1 #convert the index of _col (it has a length of len_col) to the index of  a row of U   
            
            ##################################################
            #if you remove it, then you get a lot of infinities
            #it has to do with the fact that if U[pivot][k-1] <_tiny , then U[k-1][k-1] will be a zero, 
            #L[i][k-1] explodes. 
            #You are allowed to skip this i, then, because if U[pivot][k-1] <_tiny , then all U[i][k-1] are small!
            #Check that this is true by  uncommenting print(_col)
            if Abs(U[pivot][k-1]) < _tiny  :         
                #print(_col)
                break
            ###################################################
            #if the maximum is not at k-1, swap!
            if pivot != k-1 : 
                # Permute rows k-1 and pivot in U
                
                index_swap(P,k-1,pivot)
                
                tmpU=[U[k-1][_r] for _r in range(k-1,N)]
                
                #print(U)
                for _r in range(k-1,N):
                    U[k-1][_r]=U[pivot][_r]
                #print(U)
                for _r in range(k-1,N):
                    U[pivot][_r]=tmpU[_r-(k-1)]#again we have to convert the index of tmpU
                #print(U)
                #print("=========================")
                tmpL=[L[k-1][_r] for _r in range(k-1)]
                #print(L)
                for _r in range(k-1):
                    L[k-1][_r]=L[pivot][_r]
                #print(L)
                for _r in range(k-1):
                    L[pivot][_r]=tmpL[_r]
                    
                #print(L)
                #print("========================")
                
            L[i][k-1]=U[i][k-1]/U[k-1][k-1]
           
        
            for j in range(k-1,N):
                U[i][j]=U[i][j]-L[i][k-1]*U[k-1][j]

                
    return L,U,P
```

Comment: Appreciate the input!